# Change detection in an array of data

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a file called test.xlsx for which the link can be found below. It's diagram is [image: diagram]

According to the diagram, after the 62th point, the diagram has an upward shift. Is there a way that we can recognize this point through image processing?

I used `medfilt1(list,5)` ([link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html)) in MATLAB with different sized windows, but the result was not good.

Could you give me any advice or comment?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QzBOKhSsdgY3Juc3BlaDVuaTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your code.

Comment: I am unable to find any documentation for `medfit1`, where did you find this function.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use image processing for this task?

Comment: @lida, I am assuming that you mean `medfilt1` instead of `medfit1`. I edited your question to reflect this.

Comment: @ Takeshi, yes you are right. sorry for this mistake and thank you for your edition

Comment: @lida, no problem. In addition, I would like to echo Daniel's question. Is there a specific reason that you need to use image processing? The reason we ask is that the upward shift can be found more easily through a data-based approach, rather than an image-based approach.

Comment: @ Daniel, there is no specific reason to use image processing, The only reason is, I think that, image process is a quick method for this detection. I want to consider this data set as a stream, and as soon as reach 62th point, I can to detect this change with minimum of delay.

Comment: @TakeshiH. Can you explain more about data-based approach? I try to detect this change by concept drift algorithm and MOA software, but unfortunately it's result is so bad. because this detect change with High delay.

Comment: @Adriaan, Unfortunately, i don't understand your opinion.

Comment: @lida, I was thinking the code could have (1) a running average of your data with `mean(data(1:index))` and (2) a moving average of your data `(mean(data(index-k:index))`. Then the code could do a statistical comparison of the two averages. The code would then record the values of `index` where the two averages are statistically different. The constant `k` would be adjusted based on your needs and efficacy. I'm testing this right now.

Comment: @lida that link point you to a page which shows you how to create *the shortest possible program to replicate the results*. This is handy so we can try to help you fix your code as opposed to writing the entire thing for you.

Comment: @TakeshiH. Are you able to recognize change in 62th point? Can you give me this part of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code below. The code conducts a statistical comparison, using `ztest`, between a moving average of data(index-k:index) and data(index). The link to `ztest` is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ztest.html). `ztest` tests for the null hypothesis that `data(index) = mean(data(index-k:index))`. If `ztest` returns `h=1`, the null hypothesis is rejected, concluding that `data(index) <> mean(data(index-k:index))`. In the case with your data, the `ztest` would detect upshifts or downshifts w.r.t. a specified `alpha` level.

Try this code out with your data. With `alpha=0.05`, the code is able to detect changes at `index = 48` and `index = 66`. These are the locations at which upshifts (or downshifts) occur. Note that the upshift you described occurs at `index=66` and NOT at `index=62` as you have been stating.

Also, try using different `alpha` and `k` values.

```
data=xlsread('test.xlsx');
m = length(data);

start_index = 11;
alpha = 0.05;
k = 10;

h_array = zeros(length(data),1);

for index = start_index:m
    avg = mean(data(index-k:index));
    stdev = std(data(index-k:index));
    if index > start_index        
        val = data(index);
        h = ztest(val,avg,stdev,'alpha',alpha);
        h_array(index) = h;
    end
end
```

Comment: I should add, if you want to detect the change at `index=62`, you would need to know the values of `data(62:66)`. This is because the upshift occurs during `data(62:66)`.

Also, note that `data=xlsread('test.xlsx')`, which should have been obvious from the start.

Comment: Thank you very much. your response was very useful for me.

1. What are the selection criteria for alpha and k values?
2. What did you mean by “you would need to know the values of data(62:66)” ?

Comment: Alpha sets the confidence level. With alpha = 0.05, the confidence level would be 95%. So, from a laymen's perspective, there is 95% confidence that the `val` does not come from the normal distribution defined by `avg` and `stdev.

Comment: `k` sets the the size of the window, which is used as a basis for comparison. The code compares `val` with the mean and st.dev. of the previous `k` values (there is some indexing errors with the code, so this is not entirely correct). The `k` value is set arbitrarily. Note that larger values of `k` would be more stringent than smaller values of k. By stringent, I mean that the `h` value is less likely to be 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And my second question? you said "if you want to detect the change at index=62, you would need to know the values of data(62:66)."  What did you mean?  the "test.xlsx" file is in fact error(y axis) for each batch(x axis).

Comment: I was trying to demonstrating that it would not be possible to detect the upward shift at index=62, since the upward shift occurs from index = 62 to 66. This is because the values of index = 63 to 66 are unknown at index=62.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the stored function for this purpose

```
detrend(list);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your respons. could you explain about the detrend? (I readed matlab help) and also how do you recognize the changes on the my list?